# How to reference properties in liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a Jekyll template pulling in text from data objects.

eg.

```
{% for speaker_hash in site.data.2015.speakers %}
    {% assign speaker = speaker_hash[1] %}
    <li>
      <div class="speaker">
        <img class="head" src="/img/2015/speakers/sample.jpg">
        <h2> {{ speaker.name}} </h2>
      </div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

However I would like to have each page specify what year its for with a `page.year` property.

Is it possible to create the same for loop but specify the year dynamically?

eg

```
 {% for speaker_hash in site.data.[page.year].speakers %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer yes.

1 - Your `page.year` must be a string as hash indexes are strings. So in you front matter : `year: '2015'`

2 - Get speakers depending on `page.year` :

```
{% for speaker_hash in site.data[{{page.year}}].speakers %}
```